# ADT Eclipse dies when open android layout xml files on ubuntu environment

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm developing android applications on ubuntu environment.
When I tried to open layout xml files on eclipse, eclipse immediately hangs with this logs.

Looks it's trying to find some font files but fails. Can anybody can help me with setting proper font to somewhere?

Thank you very much.

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.font.NativeFont.fontExists([B)Z+0
j  sun.font.NativeFont.fontExists(Ljava/lang/String;)Z+19
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.getX11FontName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+10
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.getFileNameFromPlatformName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;+315
j  sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.initCompositeFonts(Lsun/awt/FontConfiguration;Ljava/util/Hashtable;)V+32
j  sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.access$400(Lsun/java2d/SunGraphicsEnvironment;Lsun/awt/FontConfiguration;Ljava/util/Hashtable;)V+3
j  sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+914
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.<init>()V+44
j  sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<init>()V+1
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+72
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+92
j  java.lang.Class.newInstance0()Ljava/lang/Object;+118
j  java.lang.Class.newInstance()Ljava/lang/Object;+16
j  java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()Ljava/awt/GraphicsEnvironment;+27
j  sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>()V+107
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.lang.Class.forName0(Ljava/lang/String;ZLjava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Class.forName(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+5
j  java.awt.Toolkit$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+13
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()Ljava/awt/Toolkit;+16
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.updateFontObject()V+132
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.reset()V+121
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.<init>()V+37
j  android.graphics.Paint_Delegate.native_init()I+4
j  android.graphics.Paint.native_init()I+0
j  android.graphics.Paint.<init>(I)V+10
j  android.graphics.Paint.<init>()V+2
j  android.widget.TextView.<clinit>()V+46
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Constructor;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+72
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+5
j  java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance([Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+92
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+286
j  android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+34
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+3
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+128
j  android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(Landroid/view/View;Ljava/lang/String;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)Landroid/view/View;+7
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/View;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;Z)V+199
j  android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(Landroid/view/LayoutInflater;Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/View;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;Z)V+26
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/View;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;Z)V+6
j  android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Lorg/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser;Landroid/view/ViewGroup;Z)Landroid/view/View;+148
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/android/resources/Density;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V+80
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.StatusBar.<init>(Landroid/content/Context;Lcom/android/resources/Density;IZ)V+8
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate()Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/Result;+306
j  com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/SessionParams;)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+36
j  com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/SessionParams;)Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+12
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession()Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/api/RenderSession;+425
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IProject;Lcom/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/editors/uimodel/UiDocumentNode;Lcom/android/ide/common/rendering/LayoutLibrary;)V+113
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout()V+106
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated()V+44
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(I)V+104
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(I)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(I)V+31
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(I)V+54
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.selectDefaultPage(Ljava/lang/String;)V+79
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages()V+6
j  com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.addPages()V+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages()V+1
j  org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)V+16
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPart;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite;)Z+3
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create()V+99
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute()Ljava/lang/Object;+84
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V+176
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Ljava/util/ArrayList;)V+42
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;)V+174
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;+345
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;+11
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+13
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(Lorg/osgi/framework/Bundle;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Lorg/eclipse/emf/common/util/URI;)Ljava/lang/Object;+169
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+90
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+4
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+124
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+21
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+535
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)Ljava/lang/Object;+168
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/internal/workbench/swt/PartRenderingEngine;Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)Ljava/lang/Object;+2
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run()V+13
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/ISafeRunnable;)V+5
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)Ljava/lang/Object;+15
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)V+196
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run()V+11
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+121
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+91
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+108
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+5
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)V+33
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;Ljava/security/Permission;)V+66
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/internal/event/EventHandlerWrapper;Ljava/security/Permission;ILorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)V+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;ILjava/lang/Object;)V+15
J  org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(Ljava/util/Set;Lorg/eclipse/osgi/framework/eventmgr/EventDispatcher;ILjava/lang/Object;)V
j  org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ILjava/lang/Object;)V+67
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;Z)V+215
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)V+3
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(Lorg/osgi/service/event/Event;)V+5
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Z+42
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(Lorg/eclipse/emf/common/notify/Notification;)V+54
j  org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(Lorg/eclipse/emf/common/notify/Notification;)V+29
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)V+119
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/basic/MWindow;Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)V+117
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/MUIElement;)V+53
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/basic/MPart;)V+5
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/basic/MPart;)V+140
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/basic/MPart;Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/modeling/EPartService$PartState;)Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ui/basic/MPart;+122
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+414
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(Lorg/eclipse/ui/internal/WorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+10
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run()V+33
j  org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+116
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZILorg/eclipse/ui/IMemento;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+61
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;ZI)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+8
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorInput;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+5
j  org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IFile;ZZ)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+36
j  org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(Lorg/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchPage;Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IFile;Z)Lorg/eclipse/ui/IEditorPart;+4
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.execute(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ExecutionEvent;)Ljava/lang/Object;+180
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.handlers.OpenResourceHandler.run(Lorg/eclipse/jface/action/IAction;)V+8
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.ActionDelegateHandlerProxy.execute(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ExecutionEvent;)Ljava/lang/Object;+185
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Ljava/util/Map;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Lorg/eclipse/core/expressions/IEvaluationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+107
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute()Ljava/lang/Object;+84
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;+104
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/di/suppliers/PrimaryObjectSupplier;)Ljava/lang/Object;+13
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+118
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(Lorg/eclipse/core/commands/ParameterizedCommand;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+66
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+77
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(Ljava/util/List;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+14
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+172
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/bindings/keys/KeyBindingDispatcher;Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+2
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+13
J  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)Z+12
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+7
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;Z)V+73
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Event;)V+4
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(ILorg/eclipse/swt/internal/gtk/GdkEventKey;)Z+62
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.gtk_key_press_event(JJ)J+23
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(JJ)J+100
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(JJ)J+3
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(JJJ)J+420
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(JJJ)J+327
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Tree.windowProc(JJJ)J+148
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(JJJ)J+20
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(J)V+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(J)V+8
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(JJ)J+132
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+0
j  org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(JZ)Z+9
j  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch()Z+36
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run()V+606
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;Lorg/eclipse/e4/core/contexts/IEclipseContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
j  org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(Lorg/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/MApplicationElement;)V+20
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run()V+256
j  org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Lorg/eclipse/core/databinding/observable/Realm;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)V+12
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+18
j  org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(Lorg/eclipse/swt/widgets/Display;Lorg/eclipse/ui/application/WorkbenchAdvisor;)I+2
j  org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(Lorg/eclipse/equinox/app/IApplicationContext;)Ljava/lang/Object;+108
j  org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+135
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+103
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+29
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+149
j  org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run([Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Runnable;)Ljava/lang/Object;+183
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework([Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/net/URL;)V+211
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun([Ljava/lang/String;)V+126
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run([Ljava/lang/String;)I+4
j  org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+10
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Comment: This issue is self-fixed by myself while installing pastie to my PC. 'sudo apt-get upgrade' Command helped me :)